# Right way of working with connectMode for VS add-ins

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, vsx, extensibility

Can someone point me to a guide on how to interpret the connectMode parameter that gets passed when a VS add-in is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out [Carlos Quintero's article](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008004.aspx) discussing this as well as the [documentation on the enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.ext_connectmode.aspx).